# Logism: Rising-Edge J-K flip-flop outputs 0 when J = 1 and K = 0

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, flipflop, memory

According to the truth table of the J-K flip-flop:

[image]

When J = 1, K = 0, and CLK (Clock Signal) = 1, Q = 1. [image]

FYI, the flip-flop is a **Rising-Edge** flip-flop. Below are the timing diagrams which show the values of J_input, K_input, OfficialClock, and Give_Merchandise as a function of time. When J = 1, K = 0, and CLK (Clock Signal) = 1, my flip-flop outputs 0 in **Column 8** of the below timing diagram (which is obviously contradictory to the truth table).

```
J_input:          0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
K_input:          1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
OfficialClock:    1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
Give_Merchandise: 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Showing static values of these signals is not at all helpful. We need to see timing diagrams that show the relationships of these signals as a function of time.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Updated question to show timing diagrams.

Comment: Your timing diagrams indicate that the clock, J, and K are all changing at exactly the same instant in time. That is not allowed; it violates the setup/hold requirements of the FF and gives unpredictable behavior.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Any ways to mitigate this error?

Comment: You must set the values of J and K, **allow a small time to pass**, and then change the clock from 0 to 1.

Comment: In Logisim you can delay a signal by a chain of buffers. Each buffer adds a little delay. But beware, Logisim is not modelling the real world. -- Why is your data signal for J and K changing at the same time as the clock? This is the main reason of confusion.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Can both the J input and the CLK (Clock Signal) of the flip-flop change at the same time? In my current solution, the J, K, and CLK inputs change at the same time (3), but if I reduce the number of inputs changed to 2, will the flip-flop still change output?

Comment: @thebusybee Can both the J input and the CLK (Clock Signal) of the flip-flop change at the same time? In my current solution, the J, K, and CLK inputs change at the same time (3), but if I reduce the number of inputs changed to 2, will the flip-flop still change output?

Comment: No. Change J and K. Wait some non-zero amount of time. Change CLK from 0 to 1.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Is there a form of memory that does not have a setup/hold delay and allows for inputs and the clock signal to simultaneously change at the same time?

Comment: From your comment at an answer below: "_place a buffer after the "c" tunnel to delay the J-K inputs?_": If you want to delay J and K, yes, insert buffers on their wires. But since you want to latch the signal that comes at (nearly) the same time, you will need to delay the clock signal. -- With simulators, there can be memories without setup and/or hold constraints, but you need to look up the documentation for the exact behaviour, though. On real devices you always have these constraints, you can't circumvent physical laws.

Answer (score 2):

There is no contradiction. The behaviour of the simulator is correct. If you drive the inputs of flip-flop EXACTLY at the clock edge, then those values are not guaranteed to be sampled at that clock edge. It will be sampled only at the next clock edge. At least that's what I have observed in many of the logic simulators. You can confirm this if you see that the expected output for J=1, K=0, has indeed appeared in the next clock edge in your timing diagram (last column).

In real world, driving flip-flop inputs at the exact clock edge is a timing violation of setup/hold. You might want to delay the J, K inputs by small amount, say half clock cycle or so, so that the behaviour won't be confusing anymore in the timing diagram.

Comment: Can both the J input and the CLK (Clock Signal) of the flip-flop change at the same time? In my current solution, the J, K, and CLK inputs change at the same time (3), but if I reduce the number of inputs changed to 2, will the flip-flop still change output?

Comment: Rising-edge triggered JK flip-flop works based on what value are stable at J, K when CLK changes from 0 -> 1. In your case, the inputs J, K are not stable but transiting at the rising edge of CLK. So simulator didn't sample it and took the past values of J, K.

Comment: @AdamLee Simulators do it in some way, hopefully documented. Inspect Logisim's documentation, please. -- The real world, however, is commonly well documented. You need to consult the FF's data sheet and obey the setup and hold times. Note that some FFs might have negative setup or negative hold times. Such times make changes on clock and J/K at the same time valid, but you need to think hard on the result.

Comment: @MituRaj Is there a form of memory that does not have a setup/hold delay and allows for inputs and the clock signal to simultaneously change at the same time?

Comment: @thebusybee Is there a form of memory that does not have a setup/hold delay and allows for inputs and the clock signal to simultaneously change at the same time?

Comment: In other words, place a **buffer after the "c" tunnel** to delay the J-K inputs, correct?

Comment: I didn't say you cannot change inputs simultaneously with the clock edge. In real world, you can't, but in functional/logic simulators, you can. Because they consider setup and hold times only in timing based simulations. But anyway the output corresponding to that input will appear only in the next clock edge. Because flip-flop is not a combinational circuit, it's sequential and synchronous.

Comment: Kindly accept an answer as solution if it solved your problem.